# If search box is empty in my list, I want the list to not show any rows

Tags: 2013, list, web-part

I have a list web part that I want to show up without results until the "Find an item" box has been searched. In other words, the default return should be null. I can't find how to do this through the out of the box sharepoint 2013. Is there a way to do this without code? If not, any help with coding it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Robert

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Client-side rendering can be used to achieve this. You can override the PreRender of the desired ListView and write code to not show any items when search box is empty.

Please refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) article to know how CSR works.

Comment: Thank you for the above. I'm afraid it is a little above my pay grade. Could you possibly give me an example of having the list as null if search box is empty? Thanks!